# Meteor OAuth2 Server

Tags: node.js, meteor, oauth, oauth-2.0

I need to make a Meteor website into an OAuth 2 server and I'm not finding a lot available. There are lots of OAuth clients:

- https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/oauth
- https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/oauth1
- https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/oauth2

But few servers/providers.

- https://atmospherejs.com/khanghoang/oauth2-provider - Basic, not fully functional

I can't tell is this provides server capabilities as the documentation is light:

- https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/accounts-oauth

I'm considering converting thomseddon's node-oauth2-server over to a meteor package, but want to know if there is something else available:

- https://github.com/thomseddon/node-oauth2-server

Comment: I am also facing this problem

Comment: I am currently writing an OAuth server code example for Meteor which uses the OAuth2orize library. I will post a link to the code once it is complete.

Answer (score 2):

I work for Prime8Consulting and we just finished writing an oauh2 client/server package for meteor. It has lots of documentation and example applications that demonstrate how it works. https://github.com/prime-8-consulting/meteor-oauth2

We are excited to get feedback.

Comment: What do you mean with "lots of documentation"? Inside the doc folder there are only 2 pictures and that's all. Do you have another link?

Comment: Read the readmes in each of the examples folder. Running the examples gives you a thorough walk through of the oauth2 process. Also, the code is highly documented as well.